# How do I get rid of the UTA002/UTA005/UTA006 warnings for my generic base test class?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a few test classes that do similar things, need similar initialization and cleanup and similar instance variables. Thus, I created a base class and defined the `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` attributes on them:

```
Public Class ImportTestBase(Of T As {ImportBase, New})
    ' ...Some instance variables and protected properties...

    <TestInitialize()>
    Public Sub Init()
        ' Connect to Test-DB, start a transaction, instantiate the import class T
    End Sub

    <TestCleanup()>
    Public Sub Cleanup()
        ' Rollback the transaction, do other cleanup stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

This reduces boilerplate code in my actual test classes:

```
<TestClass()>
Public Class AddressImportTests
    Inherits ImportTestBase(Of MyAddresImportClass)

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub SomeTest()
        ' Test something here
    End Sub

    ' No boilerplate Init and Cleanup here. Yippie!
End Class
```

**This works great!** Unfortunately, the Visual Studio (2015) test runner outputs some ugly warnings:

```
UTA005: Illegal use of attributes on MyNamespace.ImportTestBase`1.Init.The TestInitializeAttribute can be defined only inside a class marked with the TestClass attribute.
UTA006: Illegal use of attributes on MyNamespace.ImportTestBase`1.Cleanup. The TestCleanupAttribute can be defined only inside a class marked with the TestClass attribute.
```

This bothers me, because I don't like to ignore warnings. Adding `TestClass` to the test base class does not help; on the contrary:

```
UTA002: TestClass attribute  cannot be defined on generic class MyNamespace.ImportTestBase`1.
UTA005: Illegal use of attributes on MyNamespace.ImportTestBase`1.Init.The TestInitializeAttribute can be defined only inside a class marked with the TestClass attribute.
UTA006: Illegal use of attributes on MyNamespace.ImportTestBase`1.Cleanup. The TestCleanupAttribute can be defined only inside a class marked with the TestClass attribute.
```

Any idea on how to get rid of them?

Comment: When I have done this, I have not put the TestInitialize and TestCleanup attributes on the base class methods.  In the actual tests, my TestInitialize and TestCleanup do have those attributes and call base.TestInitialize() and base.TestCleanup (in C#, sorry I don't know VB).  This all works fine.

Comment: @JeffPrince: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as a workaround.

Comment: From my experience, a TestClass that uses generics has to be abstract (MustInherit in VB)

Comment: @JET: That's it, the warning is gone. Thanks a lot! Please add that as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your base class abstract (C#) or MustInherit (VB).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the vstest console instead.